# Sidebars and header no longer expressed but blocks are still defined

Tags: 6, blocks

I inherited a Drupal 6.28 site using theme Colourise 6.x-2.1.  I do PHP dev but am not very familiar with Drupal.

Today without having modified any files and without having made other updates none of the content displayed by Blocks is being rendered.

I checked in /?q=admin/build/block and all of my blocks have same left sidebar, right sidebar, header, and top content data as before.  Most are just static html.

I am able to rearrange, cut throttle on and off and changes are preserved in admin but the contents are still not rendered at all.

I cleared cache to no effect.

Problem persists across theme changes so I assume it's not the page.tpl.ph file.

For kicks I edited conditionals around sidebars in Colourize theme page.tpl.php and saw the empty divs for them render.

I was able to add and save a new HTML block in admin and move it to sidebars and header and save location but it never rendered.

What should be my next step to debug this?

Comment: do any blocks render at all? for example, if you create a new block that just says hello world, does it render?  Do you have any modules installed that affect blocks, or their content that could be the culprit? If you change themes (temporarily) or use a default page.tpl.php will they render?

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  I added a new block with just <h1>Test</h1> and was able to save placed in header and sidebar but it did not render either place.  Also tried moving, adding disabled blocks, and disabling existing blocks but none of these affected it.

Comment: AFAIK I do not have any modules that affect blocks.  Will see if I can get a default page.tpl.php file

Comment: Problem persists across theme changes so I assume it's not the page.tpl.ph file

Comment: hmm.. that would have been too easy :)  next I might check the log to see if there are any errors of note, and then review permissions

Comment: Thank you!  Wasn't aware of the logging interface.  Looks like server is having a subtle issue.  Joins are set up to be written to /tmp but are throwing /#1 - Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_802_0.MYI' (Errcode: 30)'.  Have host addressing.